# Creating contours from DEM for multiple files using ArcMap ModelBuilder?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, modelbuilder, dem

How can i create an ArcMap model in ModelBuilder to iterate through a folder and applying contouring tool on all tif DEM files on that folder.

Answer (score 1):

The best way to accomplish that task would be to use an iterator.
When ModelBuilder is open, select Insert - Iterator - Rasters.

[image]

You can then select the file in which the DEMs are stored, and connect to the Contour tool. 
[image]

[Here](http://resources.arcgis.com/EN/HELP/MAIN/10.2/index.html#//00400000001n000000) is also a handy link about using iterators

Comment: I do use iterator but when i try to run it, it gives me error that can not open feature class that is output genearted...

Comment: Can you post a picture of your model and the error?